# Outputing content from db generate double line breaks

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with collation latin1_swedish_ci.

The field look like this in the DB:

[image]

When outputing I do like this:

```
echo str_replace("<br />", "\n", trim($post->getContent()));
```

$post->getContent() is just fetching the field from the DB, no manupalating from DB to echo.

The thing is when I update the field I get double line breaks (just updating without adding line breaks).

How come I get this and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<br />` completely, you already have an `\n` in database, you are making 2 new lines when you replace `<br />` with `\n`:

```
echo str_replace("<br />", "", trim($post->getContent()));
```